# Autocompletar Bootstrap-Codeigniter-php

Tags: php, bootstrap, codeigniter

Quisiera que me ayuden, no encuentro el error, veo q me devuelve los datos, pero no se muestran. Estoy tratando de auto-completar usando bootstrap

Vista:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[name=codigo]").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/articulo/getarticulos",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            if (ui.item.id) {
                $("[name=codigo]").val(ui.item.codigo);
                return false;
            }
        },
        search: function (event, ui ) {
            $("[name=codigo]").val(0);
        }
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6"> 
        <div class='input-group'>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span></span>                
            <input id="txtcodigo" name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="Codigo" value="" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Controlador:

```
public function getarticulos()
{
    $q              = trim($this->input->get('term'));     
    $where          = array('like codigo' => $q);
    $productoresult = $this->articulo_model->All($where);
    $result         = array();

    foreach ($productoresult as $i => $articulo) {
        $result[$i]['id']           = $articulo->id;
        $result[$i]['codigo']       = $articulo->codigo;
        $result[$i]['descripcion']  = $articulo->descripcion;
        $result[$i]['precioactual'] = $articulo->precioactual;
    }          
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Modelo:

El método `all` lo hereda de la clase `CI_MODEL(system->core->Model)`, que viene en el Codeigniter, yo lo hago tal cual en otro proyecto, y me funciona perfecto el auto-completar, pero ahora estoy usan bootstrap en otro proyecto y no aparece en la vista los datos. y no me tira ningún error.

```
class Articulo_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('articulo', NULL, 'Articulo_Model');     
    }
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: que librerias de js estás usando? que has intentado hasta el momento? la función en select es llamada?

Comment: buenas estoy usando: bootstrap.min.js,jquery-1.10.2.js,jquery-1.7.1.min.js,jquery-1.11.1.min.js, te agradeceria si m ayudaras :)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno yo también batalle para hacerlo funcionar pero con este código me funciona:

Modelo

```
public function ListaMunicipios()
{
    $this->db->order_by('id_municipio ASC');
    return $this->db->get('municipio')->result();
}
```

Controlador

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('arr_mpo',$this->aretado_model->ListaMunicipios());
```

En donde quiere que se active el autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$i=0;
$mpo = array();
  foreach ($this->session->flashdata('arr_mpo') as $key) {
      $mpo[$i] = $key->nombre_municipio;
        $i++;
 }  ?>
 listMPO = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $mpo).'"' ?>];

</script>

<? $nombre = array(
                'name'        => "nombre",
                'id'          => "nombre",
                'size'        => "35",
                'class'       => "form-control autocomplete",
                'placeholder' => "NOMBRE Y/O APELLIDO"
               );echo form_input($_upp);?>

$('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        /*source: autocompletar,*/
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(autocompletar, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 10));
        },
        minLength: 2
});
```

Me base en estos links, espero sean de ayuda!

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget--net-10560

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/vqwBP/

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Jaz, muy amable por responderme, sabes me parece q mi problema esta en el tema de las librerias de js para autocompletar, vos cual utilizas? xq a mi en la consola tengo los datos de la lista q quiero q muestre, pero no se visualizan en la vista, desde ya muchas gracias :)

Comment: Jquery UI Autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Disculpa por tardar en responder espero poder ayudarte :)